# writes several line to standard out put in reverse order

Tags: java

I want to write a program in java that takes all the lines input to standard input and writes them to standard output in reverse order.
this is may code but it has an error and I can't understand where is the problem
(In this program at first I ask for the number of lines and then save it in 'n'.)
any help?
thanks in advance

```
 package getLine;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class S {
   public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("how many lines do you want to enter");
    int n= s.nextInt();
    String [] str;
    str= new String[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        str[i]=s.nextLine();
    for(int i=n;i>=0;i--)
        System.out.println(str[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: please mention what error  u get

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
 at getLine.S.main(S.java:14

Comment: @ShN - Check my answer. The way you consume the input needs to be changed a bit.

Comment: thank you all for paying attention. all of you were right. 'n' was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the code with output:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class S {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("how many lines do you want to enter");
    int n = s.nextInt();

    System.out.println("I want to enter " + n + " lines ");
    n = n + 1;
    String[] str;
    str = new String[n];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        str[i] = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str[i]);
        count++;
    }
    if (count == n) {
        System.out.println("Reversed output");

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
how many lines do you want to enter
2
I want to enter 2 lines 

1
1
2
2
Reversed output
2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a `Stack<String>` to buffer the lines? Then simply pop every line and output it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    System.out.println(str[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? The error lies here:

```
  for(int i=n;i>=0;i--)
    System.out.println(str[i]);
```

In the first step of that loop you attempt to print str[n], which doesn't exist. 
Your array consists of n elements numbered from 0 to n-1.

The proper code is:

```
  for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      System.out.println(str[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from `n-1` because the maximum index accessible in an array is `array.length-1`.

```
for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
```

Also you need to make this change:-

```
int n= Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
```

`s.nextInt()` reads the next integer all right, but the enter you hit after that, is consumed as the first element of your array. To avoid that, you can do as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do much to handle this, just replace your line in a code by the following code-

```
int n = s.nextInt()+1;
```